# Is my app version a sensitive information

Tags: security, deployment

To make maintenance and versions tracking easier, I would like to expose the app version of each of the applications I develop on all my environnements.

Can the app version and the last deploy datetime of my own application be considered as a sensitive information that should not be public ? Is it professional to do this ?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: I guess it can give an attacker some clues about what environnement is patched or not. But I do not work on big tools like Wordpress or Drupal, I'm not on exploit-db.com, exploits have to be crafted for my app, so I'm maybe overthinking...

Comment: For a related concern, consider that OWASP recommends removing Tomcat's version string as one (minor) step of [securing it](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat#Installation_of_Apache_Tomcat). Of course, Tomcat's vulnerabilities for specific versions are probably more well-known to attackers than those of your custom software.

Comment: @AndresF. I've had pen testers demand we replace the session IDs and the sessionid request parameter with custom names so even the fact that we were using application server X was hidden from the person accessing the application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A version number is a minimal hindrance to an attacker and a great help to defenders.  Frequently, attackers will just try an exploit without bothering to check a version number.  I get several windows-based attack attempts per hour in my snort logs, and I haven't owned a windows machine in decades.  The exploit working is the only confirmation they need.

On the other hand, the vast majority of your users aren't going to download or create an exploit to see if they are still vulnerable to a bug.  They depend on being able to check their version number against a list of patched versions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.
What kind of application are we talking about?

1. Do a lot of other applications/sites depend on it, and do they have to update to newer versions themselves?
   *(if they use your API, you just re-deploy and everbody uses the new version. If they have to download and install a new version of your app, most of them will do it later or never)*
2. Is it public? (i.e. publically visible on the internet?)
3. Is the source code public?

If the answers to all questions is "yes", you probably shouldn't expose your version number.
If most or all of the answers are "no", it's probably not *that* dangerous.

---

### Example 1: nginx

[One of the other answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/345081/3826) uses nginx as an example.
For nginx, the answer to all three above questions is "yes".

This is clearly an example where the version number should **not** be exposed:

- no one needs to know the version number of a nginx-powered server except its administrator, so there's no need to make it public
- a **lot** of sites are running nginx, so vulnerabilities affect basically half the internet
- if a vulnerability is found, every hacker can find out how to exploit it by inspecting the source code
  (and when it's fixed, everybody can see how it was done)
- when a vulnerability is fixed, there are still millions of servers running vulnerable versions of nginx and some of them won't ever be updated

---

### Example 2: Stack Exchange

Scroll down this very site (or any other site in the SE network), and you'll see this:
[image: Stack Exchange version number]

Stack Overflow and all its sister sites are publically visible, but their source code is private **and** they control all public instances.

- it's harder to find vulnerabilities without the source code
- even if a vulnerability is found: the SE team just has to fix it and re-deploy all sites, and then they know there's **no** site on the whole internet still running the vulnerable version.

So showing the version number should be no big risk, and apparently they decided to show it.

(on the other hand, it probably makes deploying and testing easier - deploy to **one** of ten load-balanced servers, open the site in a browser and see which version you're running)

---

### Example 3: Internal software

My day job is a closed-source, non-web, LOB application for company-internal use.

- the app auto-updates itself on startup
- people start working at different times (night shifts!)
- we often deploy during the day

This means we can't make sure everybody is always running the newest version, and when bug reports come in, we want to know which version they were using.

So the top bars of the main window and all message boxes say something like **OurLOBApp (Version 1.23, 29 Mar 2017)**, so this information is guaranteed to be on every screenshot we ever get.

The app has only about 200 users and most of them are non-technical...so showing the version number in this environment is definitely no risk at all because nearly nobody knows what a "vulnerability" or "source code" is :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of exposing versioning if, as you've noted, when the software is common between multiple applications from different vendors.

For example, take a look at `nginx`; used by millions of users and companies. If some exploit is found, all those users may be exposed if the current version is shown on every HTTP request in the `Server` header.

On the other hand, your applications are probably managed by you. if you found and exploit, the current version of your application will be susceptible to attacks, no matter if the version is exposed or not.

However, if the current version does not provide any useful information to the user, why would you show it? This can be useful for desktop apps to diagnose common client problems, but for web applications, unless you've some type of cache system, I think there is *no need* on exposing the

Comment: I need to expose it for bug reporting, so that user know which version they are using